# Is there a list of which of the diphthongs in the English language are wide and which are narrow available?

Tags: diphthongs

I added diphthongs like [aɪ](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q24074479) and [ɪə](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q24206668) to Wikidata. I added them to groups of whether they are closing or centering.

I would also like to add them to group based on whether they are wide or narrow as I read that this is an additional property in which they differ. I however can't find a good list that defines which diphthongs are wide and which are narrow. Can someone point me to a good resource or give himself a list?

Comment: Where are you getting the wide/narrow terminology? This is not standard phonetic terminology AFAIK.

Comment: @TKR : Wikipedia for example lists 4 distinctions for [diphthongs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diphthong): `Rising and Falling`, `Closing, Opening and Centering`, `wide and narrow` and `length`.

Comment: Hmm. Seems like this isn't a binary distinction but a matter of degree, if it's defined as "how far in the vowel space the end point is from the start point".

Answer (score 1):

First of all, a caveat: I'd never heard the terms "wide" and "narrow" applied to diphthongs before this question, and after some searching still haven't seen them anywhere except Wikipedia's "Diphthong" article. So I wouldn't say they're particularly standard or widespread.

But, using Wikipedia's definition, if you plot the start and end of the diphthong on an F1/F2 vowel chart (like the IPA one), the "width" is the distance between them.

Using this definition, `/aj/` and `/aw/` are "wide", while `/ej/` and `/ow/` are "narrow". The centering diphthongs you get in non-rhotic dialects are somewhere in the middle.